# Call a function defined inside another function on the same object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var myfunction = function (obj1){

   init = function(){
     ///object operation
     func1();
   }

   func1 = function(){
      some operation
   }

}
```

In the above code there is a function called func1, defined inside myfunction operates on some object. Inside myfunction(), func1() is called to change the object, I want to call this object directly.

Comment: do you want to access obj1 inside func1?

Comment: I want to access func1 outside of myfunction which still acts on the same object

Comment: return func1. check closures.

Comment: read the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/3975492

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var func1 = ''
var myfunction = function(obj1) {
  func1 = function(p, v) {
    return p + ' - ' + v;
  }
  var init = function(data) {
    return func1(obj1, data);
  }
  return init;
}
var d = myfunction('Hellow');
var result = d('world')
console.log('Inside call ', result)
console.log('Dirct call', func1('Hellow', 'World'))
```